# How to calculate the integral curves for the vector field $V(x,y) = (y, -3y-2x)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vectors, curves

I need to show that all the integral curves for the vector field $V(x,y) = (y, -3y-2x)$ meet at the origin in order to solve a problem on PDEs (that you can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379072/existence-of-non-constant-solutions-for-a-linear-first-order-pde-in-mathbbr)).

I did the following:

$ \frac{dx}{dt} = y \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = -3y-2x   $

Assuming proper smoothness conditions, we have:

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = -3\frac{dy}{dt} - 2\frac{dx}{dt} = -3\frac{dy}{dt} - 2y$.

I solved it with Wolfram Mathematica, that gave $y(t) = c_1e^{-2t} + c_2e^{-t}$. One then easily proceeds to get $x(t) = -\frac{c_1}{2}e^{-2t} - c_2e^{-t} + c_3$.

However, when the input given to the software is the original system, the solution it gives is $x(t) = -c_1 e^{-2 t}+2 c_1 e^{-t}-c_2 e^{-2 t}+c_2 e^{-t}$, $y(t) = 2 c_1 e^{-2 t}-2 c_1 e^{-t}+2 c_2 e^{-2 t}-c_2 e^{-t}$.

Using the second, it is easily seen that $lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}(x(t), y(t)=(0,0)$, what then solves the problem. However, how can I explain the discrepancies?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that the integral curves "meet at the origin" only in the sense that _in the limit as $t \to \infty$_, every integral curve approaches the origin. (That is, the curves do not "go through" the origin in the conventional sense.) Does that help?

Comment: Indeed it does. However, performing the calculations again, I noticed that I missed a constant factor in $x(t)$, what invalidates the solution. When I give as input the original system, Mathematica, gives back different functions. Could you notice any mistake in my solution? I remark that the new solution satisfies the smoothness assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this one out. We want to solve the following system of linear ODEs:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = y \\ 
\frac{dy}{dt} = -3y -2x
$

The matrix of coefficients is 
$ A = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0  & 1 \\
-2 & -3 
\end{array}
\right]
$. It has eigenvalues -1 and -2 associated with the eigenvectors $(-a, a); a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(b, -2b); b \in \mathbb{R}$. The general solution is then

$ x(t) = c_1e^{-t} + c_2e^{-2t} \\
y(t) = -c_1e^{-t} -2 c_2e^{-2t}
$.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer once you worked it out :)

Comment: I hope this helps others :)

Comment: In any linear problem (even where solutions of a PDE may be added together), eigensolutions play a huge role. The solutions to eigenvectors are always simple to solve (i.e. they are exponentially decaying here). And the eigenspace spans the entire vector space, so you may break up your equation into eigen-components and add the solutions together. This is only possible in linear problems, and you will find it a pervasive theme if you continue your studies.